# Python loop storing heads and tales data

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and one task I read is make a small loop with heads or tales, and collect the data in the end of how many Tales or Heads was faced.

Here's my code

```
import random

x = random.randrange(2)
y = ["Tales","Heads"]
tales = 0
heads = 0
for i in range(100):
    print(y[x])
    x = random.randrange(2)
    if y == "Tales":
        tales += 0
    elif y == "Heads":
        heads += 0

print("it was", heads,"heads and ",tales,"tales.")
```

What error have I made? 
Loop is really something difficult to learn.

Thank you everyone, I did put heads += 1 at first and didn't work, what I was missing was the if y[x] == "tales".

Again, thanks to everyone that replied.

Comment: accept answer which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issuesin your code -

1. You should compare your for *Heads* or *Tales*  using `y[x]`
2. count should be increased by **1**, not **0**. *example* -  `tales += 1`

```
import random

x = random.randrange(2)
y = ["Tales","Heads"]
tales = 0
heads = 0
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(2)
    print(y[x])
    if y[x] == "Tales":
        tales += 1
    elif y[x] == "Heads":
        heads += 1

print("it was", heads,"heads and ",tales,"tales.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues in this code. Firstly you're trying to increment the tales/heads results by 0 (`tales += 0`), when they should be done by 1. Also, you can't check the result like this `if y == "Tales":`. You'd have to assign it to another variable. Try something like the following.

```
import random

x = random.randrange(2)
y = ["Tales","Heads"]
tales = 0
heads = 0
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(2)
    chosenValue  = y[x];
    if chosenValue == "Tales":
        tales += 1
    elif chosenValue == "Heads":
        heads += 1

    print("it was", heads, "heads and ", tales, "tales.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `1` not `0`

```
tales += 1
```

and

```
heads += 1
```

Of course you have to compare text with `y[x]` , not `y`.

`y[x]` gives you single text from list.

Comment: Whilst this is an issue with the code, it would not fix the OPs problem. Neither would increment even with your suggested changes because these lines are broken ```if y == "Tales"```.

Comment: At first I saw this problem and I did't  look for more problems :)